# .net ContextUtil TDC object

Tags: .net, transactions, com+, msdtc, distributed-transactions

According to the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.contextutil.aspx

Is there a differences between the following options:

1. Call only: ContextUtil.SetComplete()

   " Sets the consistent bit and the done bit to true in the COM+ context"
2. Call both:

   - ContextUtil.DeactivateOnReturn = True

     " Sets the done bit in the COM+ context"
   - ContextUtil.MyTransactionVote = TransactionVote.Commit

     "When MyTransactionVote is set to Commit, the COM+ consistent bit is set to true and
     the COM+ context votes to commit the transaction"